# How to use recursive function in Lua to dynamically build a table without overwriting it each call

Tags: recursion, lua

I have a need to crawl a set of data of indeterminate size and build a table key/value index of it. Since I don't know the dimensions in advance, seems I have to use a recursive function. My Lua skills are very new and superficial. I'm having difficulty understanding how to deal with returning a table from the function call.

Note this is for a **Lua 5.1** script processor

```
API = function(tbl)
  local table_api = {}
  -- do stuff here with target data and add to table_api
  table_api["key"] = value
  -- then later there is a need to recurse deeper into target data
  table_api["lower"] = API(var)
  return table_api
end

result = API(source_data)
```

In most every other language I know there would be some way to make the recurse line `table_api["lower"] = API(var)` work but since Lua does table variables by reference, my return sub-table just keeps getting overwritten and my result is a tiny last bit of what it should be.

**Just for background on my purpose:** there's a commercial application I'm working with that has a weakly documented Lua scripting interface. It's running Lua 5.1 and the API is not well documented and frequently updated. As I understand it, everything is stored in _G, so I wanted to write something to reverse engineer the API. I have a working recursive function (not shown here) that enumerates all of _G. For that return value, it just builds up an annotated string and progressively builds on the string. That all works fine and is really useful, but it shows much more that the API interface; all the actual data elements are included, so I have to sift through like 30,000 records to determine an API set of about 500 terms. In order to determine the API, I am trying to use this sub-table return value recursive function being discussed in this question. The code I'm showing here is just a small distilled subset of the larger function.

I'll go ahead and include the full code here. I was hoping to incrementally build a large'ish table of each API level, any sublevels, and finally whatever keys used at the lowest level.

**In the end, I was expecting to have a table that I could address like this:**

`result["api"]["label"]["api"]["sublabel"]["value"]["valuename"]`

**Full code:**

```
tableAPIShow = function(tbl, table_track)
  table_track = table_track or {}
  local table_api = {}

  if type(tbl) == 'table' then
    -- Check if values are tables.
    local parent_table_flag = true
    for ind,val in pairs(tbl) do
      if type(val) ~= 'table' then
        parent_table_flag = false
        break
      end
    end

    -- If all children are table type, check each of them for subordinate commonality
    local api_flag = false
    if parent_table_flag == true then
      local child_table = {}
      local child_table_flag = false
      api_flag = true
      for ind,val in pairs(tbl) do
        -- For each child table, store the names of the indexes.
        for sub_ind,sub_val in pairs(val) do
          if child_table_flag == false then -- First time though, create starting template view of typical child table.
            child_table[sub_ind] = true -- Store the indexes as a template table.
          elseif child_table[sub_ind] == nil then -- Otherwise, test this child table compared to the reference template.
            api_flag = false
            break
          end
        end
        if api_flag == false then -- need to break out of nested loop
          break
        end
        child_table_flag = true
      end
    end

    if api_flag == true then
      -- If everything gets to here, then this level is an API with matching child tables below.
      for ind,val in pairs(tbl) do
        if table_api["api"] == nil then
          table_api["api"] = {}
        end
        table_api["api"][ind] = tableAPIShow(val, table_track)
      end
    else
      -- This level is not an API level, determine how to process otherwise.
      for ind,val in pairs(tbl) do
        if type(val) == 'table' then
          if table_track[val] ~= nil then -- Have we already recursed this table?
          else
            table_track[val] = true
            if table_api["table"] == nil then
              table_api["table"] = {}
            end
            table_api["table"][ind] = tableAPIShow(val, table_track)
          end
        else -- The children are not tables, they are values
          if table_api["value"] == nil then
            table_api["value"] = {}
          end
          table_api["value"][ind] = val
        end
      end
    end
  else
    -- It's not a table, just return it.
    -- Probably never use this portion because it's caught on upper level recurse and not called
    return tbl
  end
  return table_api
end
```

**And I was calling this function in the main script like this:**

`local str = tableAPIShow(_G)`

I've got another function that recursively shows a table so I can look inside my results and see I only get a return value that contains only the values of the top-level of _G (I have it excluded built-in Lua functions/values because I'm only interested in the Application API):

```
{
[value] = table: 00000000F22CB700 {
    [value][_VERSION] = Application/5.8.1 (x86_64; Windows NT 10.0.16299),
    [value][tableAPIShow] = "function: 00000000F22C6DE0, defined in (121-231) C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\APP\\/~mis00002690 ",
    [value][_FINAL_VERSION] = true,
    [value][Path] = ./Scripts/Database/elements/,
    [value][class] = "function: 00000000F1953C40, defined in (68-81) Scripts/Common/Class.lua ",
    [value][db_path] = ./Scripts/Database/,
    [value][merge_all_units] = "function: 00000000F20D20C8, defined in (2242-2250) Scripts/Database/db_merge.lua ",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to localize the variable you store your table in and it will work as you expect:

```
local table_api = {}
```

(note that you are passing `table` variable that conflicts with the global `table` variable and is not currently used in the function.)

Comment: I had tried that before and had the same effect. I clarified and expanded my original question to include the actual function I'm using. Even with the local definition I cannot seem to get the recurse return to add it to the top-level table I'm building

Answer (score 0):

Like @Paul Kulchenko said, you need to learn to use locals (https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html). Global variable post-exist until a new lua_State is loaded (a new environment, could be a new process depending on what interpreter you are using). So a tip is to always use local variables for anything you don't want to leave the function or leave the compilation unit.

Think of tables like dictionaries: a word is attached to a definition. Thusly the definition is the data.

What I think you are trying to do is serialization of a table of data. However, that isn't really necessary. You can either shadow copy or deep copy the given table. A shadow copy is when you don't delve into the depths of tables found in the keys, etc. A deep copy is when you copy tables in keys of tables in keys of tables... etc.

```
local shallow_copy = function(tab)
    local rep_tab = {}

    for index, value in pairs(tab)do
        rep_tab[index] = value
    end

    return rep_tab
end

-- because local variable is not defined or declared immediately on a 1-liner,
--   a declaration has to exist so that deep_copy can be used
--   lets metatable execute functions
local deep_copy
deep_copy = function(tab)
    local rep_tab = {}

    for index, value in pairs(tab)do
        if(type(value) == "table")then
            rep_tab[index] = deep_copy(value)
        else
            rep_tab[index] = value
        end
    end

    return rep_tab
end
```

Deco's deepcopy.lua
https://gist.github.com/Deco/3985043

You can also index tables using periods:

```
local tab = {}
tab.abc = 123
tab["def"] = 456
print(tab.abc, tab["def"])
```

To serialize the entire _G, you would just filter out the junk you don't need and recurse each table encountered. Watch out for _G, package, and _ENV because if defined it will recurse back to the start.

```
-- use cap as a whitelist
enumerate_dir = function(dir, cap)
    local base = {}

    for i, v in pairs(dir) do
        -- skip trouble
        if(i ~= "_G" and i ~= "_ENV" and i ~= "package")then
            if(type(v) == "table")then -- if we have a table
                base[i] = enumerate_dir(v, cap)
            else
                for k, n in pairs(cap) do
                    if(type(v) == n)then -- if whitelisted
                        base[i] = tostring(v)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return base
end

-- only functions and tables from _G please
local enumeration = enumerate_dir(_G, {"function", "table"})

-- do some cool quips to get a basic tree system
prefix = ""
recursive_print = function(dir)
    for i, v in pairs(dir)do
        if(type(v) == "table")then
            print(prefix, i, v)
            prefix = prefix .. ">"
            recursive_print(v)
        else
            print(prefix, i, v)
        end
    end
    if(#prefix > 0)then
        prefix = prefix:sub(1, #prefix-1)
    end
end

recursive_print(test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm aware of that deepcopy tutorial function and kind of understand it's usage. I edited and expanded my original question to include the full function I'm using. Even after trying the `local table_api = {}` I still cannot seem to get the recursive sublevel replies to add to the top-level running table.

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to believe that your tableAPIShow function code is working correctly and the

> another function that recursively shows a table

fails to serialize your table fully. Hence you don't see the deeper levels of the table returned by tableAPIShow().

I got your initial and current code (tableAPIShow) to work with my simple [table serialize function](https://github.com/VADemon/Moonlib/blob/master/serialize.lua): the whole _Global table is exported completely and formatted as you implemented it in your tableAPIShow().

Code for testing:

```
apiMassiveTable = {
    api = {
        get = {
            profile = {"profileID", "format"},
            name = {"profileID", "encoding"},
            number = {"profileID", "binary"}
        },
        set = {
            name = {"apikey", "profileID", "encoding", "newname"},
            number = {"apikey", "profileID", "binary", "newnumber"}
        },
        retrieve = {}
    },
    metadata = {version="1.4.2", build="nightly"}
}

-- tableAPIShow implemenation here

table.serialize = dofile("serialize.lua")
print(table.serialize("myNameForAHugeTable", tableAPIShow(_G)))
```

PS: Whatever serialize function you're using, it should enquote strings like `Application/5.8.1 (x86_64; Windows NT 10.0.16299)` which it does not.

Comment: You are correct! There was a logic error in that TableShow function I was using. The source for that came from a KnownGoodProject and I modified it so that it would not show the built-in Lua functions if I called it with _G. Kinda silly I posted this question at all I suppose because my original code was in fact working; I thought I had not fully understood the Lua nuanced variable copy by reference and copy by value. Normally I'm a C++ programmer so I have that liability...